# Ubuntu 18.04 turn off microphone volume auto adjust on Zoom

Tags: 18.04, sound, lubuntu, microphone, zoom-meeting

While using microphone in some applications like Zoom, The microphone volume automatically gets reduced (auto-adjusted)

I want to Turn off mic auto adjusting feature in Ubuntu 18.04. It always adjust mic volume and resulting in low volume.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is to uncheck the "Automatically adjust volume" option in the audio settings from your zoom account.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can conduct zoom meetings in peace. This issue has been affecting me for past 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

For zoom, you have to disable in

Audio settings (You can get to it from the arrow next to the microphone mute/unmute button) > Test speaker and microphone.

Uncheck *Automatically adjust volume*.

You can also install pavucontrol; but zoom overides it:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

... run with

```
pavucontrol
```

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 1):

Sign in is required for the audio settings to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app audio setting as in the screenshot found under the microphone option.

[image]